# Changing column various string formats in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been working on a dataframe where one of the column (`flight_time`) contains flight duration, all of the strings are in 3 different formats for example:

- "`07 h 05 m`"
- "`13h 55m`"
- "`2h 23m`"

I would like to change them all to `HH:MM` format and finally change the data type from `object` to `time`.

Can somebody tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to have a `time` dtype. You can have a `datetime64` (`pd.DatetimeIndex`) or a `timedelta64` (`pd.TimedeltaIndex`). In your case, I think it's better to have a `TimedeltaIndex` so you can use the `pd.to_timedelta` function:

```
df['flight_time2'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['flight_time'])
print(df)

# Output
  flight_time       flight_time2
0   07 h 05 m    0 days 07:05:00
1     13h 55m    0 days 13:55:00
2      2h 23m    0 days 02:23:00
```

If you want individual time from `datetime.time`, use:

```
df['flight_time2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['flight_time'].str.findall('\d+')
                                .str.join(':')).dt.time
print(df)

# Output
  flight_time    flight_time2
0   07 h 05 m        07:05:00
1     13h 55m        13:55:00
2      2h 23m        02:23:00
```

In this case, `flight_time2` has still `object` dtype:

```
>>> df.dtypes
flight_time     object
flight_time2    object
dtype: object
```

But each value is an instance of `datetime.time`:

```
>>> df.loc[0, 'flight_time2']
datetime.time(7, 5)
```

In the first case, you can use vectorized method while in the second version is not possible. Furthermore, you loose the `dt` accessor.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was just being stubborn and just wanting to have a "clean" look dataframe (having the datetime type but just displaying the hours), but now thanks to your answer I understand the difference between both of them and use for each type!

Comment: Oh, sorry... I thought "accepting" meant to click the upvote (which I cannot do yet do to my reputation)... now is Done, thanks again my friend